Jackson Error NoSuchFieldError ALLOW_LEADING_PLUS_SIGN_FOR_NUMBERS into webapp spring boot and HAPI FHIR client 7.4
Within a spring boot application when doing a Hapi fhir genericClient search call as below, I get error

lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_LEADING_PLUS_SIGN_FOR_NUMBERS


spring boot 2.6.2
HAPI FHIR client 7.4.0

When analysing the dependencies, I see that I have jackson 2.13.1
I wonder why I get such an exception as my configuration is rather straight forward
public <T extends IBaseResource> Bundle getAllResourcesAsBundlePageFirst(int pageSize, Class<T> returnClass) {
    Bundle bundle = genericClient.search().forResource(returnClass).encodedJson().count(pageSize)
                    .withProfile(URL_PROFILE_PORTAL_GENERIC)
                    .totalMode(SearchTotalModeEnum.ACCURATE).returnBundle(Bundle.class).execute();
    log.debug("Total Number of results: " + bundle.getTotal());
    log.debug("current Number of results: " + bundle.getEntry().size());
    return bundle;
}

The full stack of error seems to tell that the error is located into Jackson
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ALLOW_LEADING_PLUS_SIGN_FOR_NUMBERS
at ca.uhn.fhir.parser.json.jackson.JacksonStructure.createObjectMapper(JacksonStructure.java:410) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.parser.json.jackson.JacksonStructure.<clinit>(JacksonStructure.java:56) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.parser.JsonParser.doParseResource(JsonParser.java:239) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.parser.BaseParser.parseResource(BaseParser.java:647) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.parser.BaseParser.parseResource(BaseParser.java:631) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.impl.BaseClient$ResourceResponseHandler.invokeClient(BaseClient.java:691) ~[hapi-fhir-client-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.impl.BaseClient$ResourceResponseHandler.invokeClient(BaseClient.java:618) ~[hapi-fhir-client-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.impl.BaseClient.invokeClient(BaseClient.java:448) ~[hapi-fhir-client-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.impl.GenericClient$BaseClientExecutable.invoke(GenericClient.java:585) ~[hapi-fhir-client-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.impl.GenericClient$FetchConformanceInternal.execute(GenericClient.java:896) ~[hapi-fhir-client-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.impl.RestfulClientFactory.validateServerBase(RestfulClientFactory.java:323) ~[hapi-fhir-client-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.impl.RestfulClientFactory.validateServerBaseIfConfiguredToDoSo(RestfulClientFactory.java:282) ~[hapi-fhir-client-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.impl.BaseClient.invokeClient(BaseClient.java:272) ~[hapi-fhir-client-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.impl.GenericClient$BaseClientExecutable.invoke(GenericClient.java:585) ~[hapi-fhir-client-7.4.0.jar:na]
at ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client.impl.GenericClient$SearchInternal.execute(GenericClient.java:2201) ~[hapi-fhir-client-7.4.0.jar:na]
at lu.lns.portal.professional.fhir.api.service.impl.FhirServiceImpl.getAllResourcesAsBundlePageFirst(FhirServiceImpl.java:843) ~[classes/:na]
at lu.lns.portal.professional.fhir.api.controller.PractitionerController.getAllPractitionersBundle(PractitionerController.java:120) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]


You get this because you are either mixing jars from Jackson or the HAPI FHIR client version you are using isn't compatible with the Jackson version in use. Checking the Jackson wiki (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/wiki/JsonReadFeatures) this feature (and thus constant) was added in Jackson 2.14, you are on 2.13.1 which is lower. EIther downgrade the client you are using or upgrade jackson (or upgrade Spring boot to a newer version to get everything updated).

you are definitively right. I downgraded the hapi client to 6.6.0 and now it works.

@christophespielmann you should post an answer and mark it as such
